# Postgres update nested jsonb fully

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I looked through almost all relevant questions on SO and I didn't find the similar problem.

I have a following table structure (id - string, progress - jsonb, row_version - numeric):

```
{
    "id": "id1",
    "progress": {"progressId1": {"prop1": 910, "prop2": [{"sub1": "valu", "sub2": "valu"}], "prop3": "smth"}}
    "row_version": 1
}
```

I need to update 3 properties: row_version, progress#progressId1#prop1, progress#progressId1#prop2, all other properties should stay untouched.

```
update my_table set row_version = row_version + 1, progress=jsonb_set(jsonb_set(progress, '{progressId1,prop1}','911'), '{progressId1,prop2}', to_jsonb('[{"sub1": "valuNew", "sub2": "valuNew"}]'::text)) where id='id1';
```

This query works almost as expected except the fact that after update I get:

```
{
    "id": "id1",
    "progress": {"progressId1": {"prop1": 911, "prop2": "[{\"sub1\": \"valuNew\", \"sub2\": \"valuNew\"}], "prop3": "smth"}}
    "row_version": 1
}
```

The prop2 isn't part of json any more but rather string. I'm a bit confused and out of ideas because `jsonb_set` requires as a third parameters jsonb property. I tried `array` cast, and other combos.

[Working example to reproduce the issue](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yhc3e6c5)

Could someone help to explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The command you say you ran has multiple errors in it.  There is no way you ran that.  Please proofread it, then copy it back into your session and verify that it does what you say it does.

Comment: @jjanes thanks for letting me know. I rewrite this example from a bit more complicated example. I fixed one missing bracket and quote. And added the link that illustrates the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that a partial jsonb update should be done not for text type but for json:

```
update my_table set row_version = row_version + 1, progress=jsonb_set(jsonb_set(progress, '{progressId1,prop1}','911'), '{progressId1,prop2}', to_jsonb('[{"sub1": "valuNew", "sub2": "valuNew"}]'::json)) where id='id1';
```

::text -> ::json solved the issue